# How to express current date in MQL Freebase Query?

Tags: freebase, mql

Freebase's [metaweb query language](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL) can be used to retreive future events if you pass in an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date.

```json
[{
  "id":            null,
  "name":          null,
  "start_date" :   null,
  "type":          "/time/event",
  "start_date>" :  "2011-09-02"
}]​
```

^ [run this query](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%5B%7B%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22start_date%22%3Anull%2C%22type%22%3A%22%2Ftime%2Fevent%22%2C%22start_date%3E%22%3A%222011-09-02%22%7D%5D&autorun=1)

#### Does MQL support an equivalent to SQL's `NOW()` or `CURDATE()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `__now__` in timestamp fields as a special shortcut:

```json
[{
  "id":            null,
  "name":          null,
  "start_date" :   null,
  "type":          "/time/event",
  "start_date>" :  "__now__"
}]​
```

You can see a live demo of this via [this Freebase Query Editor snippet](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor/?q=%5B%7B%22id%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull,%22start_date%22%3anull,%22type%22%3a%22/time/event%22,%22start_date%3E%22%3a%22__now__%22%7D%5D&autorun=1).

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to SQL's NOW() or CURDATE in MQL. Whichever programming language you're using to send the query should have an equivalent function which you can use.

You can kind of get a list of future events by sorting them in descending order of start_date like this:

```json
[{
  "id":         null,
  "name":       null,
  "type":       "/time/event",
  "start_date": {
    "value":    null,
    "optional": false
  },
  "sort":       "-start_date.value"
}]​
```